# A new word puzzle

Tags: word, anagram

Here is a new, original puzzle that I have made! You have to find the word that I describe.

> Me, I am an introduction
>
> My anagram is past tense of what you are doing now.
>
> The homophone of my anagram is used with it in a common word riddle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are

> DEAR

> Me, I am an introduction

> Letters often start with the greeting "Dear <name>"

> My anagram is past tense of what you are doing now.

> READ is the past tense of reading, which I was doing while reading the riddle.

> The homophone of my anagram is used with it in a common word riddle.

> RED is a homophone of READ, which is used in [the newspaper riddle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newspaper_riddle)
>
> > What is black and white and red all over?