# I am a fiery animal

Tags: riddle, wordplay

In the same form as my other puzzle [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65348/a-new-word-puzzle).

> Me, I am a fiery animal.
>
> My anagram goes up.
>
> My anagram's homophone will hurt your eyes.

Comment: Is the me intentional in the first line?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are

> Aries

Me, I am a fiery animal.

> The constellation Aries is a Ram. Literally, an animal made of fire (stars)

My anagram goes up

> Aries → Raise

My anagram's homophone will hurt your eyes.

> Raise → Rays

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: Woah, really? I've never had an answer jump to me like that.  That should have taken longer solve.

Comment: I could have made it harder, but you are an expert solver :D

Comment: Also, for the first clue, it's one of the fire signs, in astrology.

Comment: That is what I was hinting at  @HerbWolfe :D