# Me, I am circumference

Tags: word, anagram

Here is a puzzle in the same form of my previous puzzles, [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65348/a-new-word-puzzle) and [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66636/i-am-a-fiery-animalhere).

> Me, I am circumference,
>
> My anagram is what you should do,
>
> My anagram's homophone is what you do in school,
>
> My anagram's other homophone is a ceremony, often in religion.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are

> **GIRTH** - the measurement around the middle of something, AKA circumference

My anagram is what you should do,

> You should do what is **RIGHT**

My anagram's homophone is what you do in school,

> In school, you **WRITE** a lot of things

My anagrams other homophone is a ceremony, often in religion

> A religious ceremony can be called a **RITE**

@QuantumTwinkie (using your anagram's other homophone's anagram):

> I hope you never **TIRE** of making these puzzles!  =D

Comment: That is the correct answer :D.

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie Nice, thank you for the puzzle!

Comment: Ha ha ha, I like the edit! @hagfy

Answer (score 5):

Totally sacrificing the appropriate meaning of "homophone", this was my first idea, heh.

You are

> **pi*d**, circumference = pi * diameter

My anagram is what you should do,

> You should **dip**—your chips. You're bland if you don't.

My anagram's homophone is what you do in school,

> **Dipping** class means ditching class.

My anagrams other homophone is a ceremony, often in religion

> Baptism is getting **dipped** in water.

Comment: This is a very clever answer! ha ha ha :D

Comment: Nice. +1, and welcome to Puzzling.SE.

Comment: So, if it were `dπ`, would it be "de apple pie", or "de steak 'n' kidn'y pie"?