# I Never do Tire!

Tags: word, anagram

[Hagfy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67646/me-i-am-circumference/67647#67647) was correct, I will never "tire" of making these puzzles! Here are the previous three: [1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65348/a-new-word-puzzle) [2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66636/i-am-a-fiery-animal)  [3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67646/me-i-am-circumference)

> Me, I am average,
>
> My homophone is what you shouldn't be,
>
> My other homophone is your intention,
>
> My homophones's anagram agrees,
>
> My homophones's other anagram is what you give people and objects,
>
> My homophones's final anagram is what you trim.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you're

> **MEAN** (but not really)

Me, I am average,

> In math, **mean** is the average of a group of numbers

My homophone is what you shouldn't be,

> You should be nice, not **mean**

My other homophone is your intention,

> Not sure what you **mean**

My homophones's anagram agrees,

> **AMEN!!!**

My homophones's other anagram is what you give people and objects,

> You **name** them

My homophones's final anagram is what you trim.

> You might trim a **mane**

Comment: Whoa, you are FAST, and right :D

Comment: That was fast! Good job!

Comment: A little too fast..

Comment: I've been at work, dealing with a plethora of other people's problems, and I felt something calling me here.  Turns out it was @QuantumTwinkie LITERALLY calling me out!  Thanks for the puzzle, and for letting me feel some success today!

Comment: @hagfy Sure no problem! Happy to share a puzzle!

Comment: I sense a kinship brewing between the two

Comment: Can't tell if you're still stuck on the third clue or not...

Comment: @maxathousand =)  Edited my answer to clarify a little.