# My homophone is sad

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Here is one of my classic puzzles ([1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65348/a-new-word-puzzle), [2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66636/i-am-a-fiery-animal), [3](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67646/me-i-am-circumference), and [4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68124/i-never-do-tire)), but this one includes opposites.

> Me, I rise,
>
> My homophone is sad,
>
> My opposite falls,
>
> My opposite's homophone saves the day,
>
> My opposite's anagram is an object.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Me, I rise,

> Morning

My homophone is sad,

> Mourning

My opposite falls,

> Night

My opposite's homophone saves the day,

> Knight

My opposite's anagram's is an object.

> Thing