# My Anagram is Coming

Tags: word, anagram

Here is another one of my classic puzzles ([1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65348/a-new-word-puzzle), [2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66636/i-am-a-fiery-animal), [3](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67646/me-i-am-circumference), [4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68124/i-never-do-tire), and [5](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71454/my-homophone-is-sad)).

> Me, I'm telling you something,
>
> My anagram is coming,
>
> My other anagram is to make something different.
>
> My Second anagram's homophone is found in the Bible.

Comment: I'll upvote in at least $28$ minutes (because of my Daily Voting Limit, DVL). I'll also be sure to upvote @nikki 's answer, because I never would have thought of that. Great riddle! :D

Comment: Upvoted! $(+1)$

Comment: Shouldn't that be second anagram's homophone?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your word is

> Alert

Me, I'm telling you something,

> Alert

My anagram is coming,

> Later

My other anagram is to make something different.

> Alter

My third anagram's homophone is found in the Bible.

> Altar

Comment: Yep, That is correct :D

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie Ah dang. I was gonna look at this answer before mine, hahah :P

Comment: Great answer! $(+1)$

Answer (score 4):

*I don't think this is the answer, but I'll give it a shot.*

---

Could your word be

> **PRONTO**?

`Me, I'm telling you something,`

> **PRONTO**.

`My anagram is coming,`

> Pronto fits, but could it also be **ON PORT**? Ships come and go to and from ports/harbours.

`My other anagram is to make something different.`

> **PROTON**. We define atoms by their number of protons (in particular, we define atomic numbers by the corresponding atom's number of protons). If the number of protons are different, the atom itself is different.

`My third anagram's homophone is found in the Bible.`

> This is a stretch, but **AMON**? It's not really a homophone, but it rhymes and sounds like **amen**.

Comment: I like the creativity :) +1

Comment: Agreed! +1 for the creativity!

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie hah, thanks. I found this riddle a bit tricky :D