# My Anagram is Noble

Tags: word, anagram

Here is another one of my classic puzzles ([1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65348/a-new-word-puzzle), [2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66636/i-am-a-fiery-animal), [3](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67646/me-i-am-circumference), [4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68124/i-never-do-tire), [5](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72420/my-anagram-is-coming) and [6](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71454/my-homophone-is-sad)).

> Me, I am what you do when you don't want to do something,
>
> My anagram is noble,
>
> My other anagram is necessary for human life,
>
> My homophone is not getting any bigger,
>
> My homophone's anagram is proved false.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is:

> Groan

*Me, I am what you do when you don't want to do something,*

> A groan is the sound you make when you don't want to do something

*My anagram is noble,*

> The anagram is 'Argon' a **noble** gas

*My other anagram is necessary for life,*

> This anagram is 'organ', which are definitely necessary for life!

*My homophone is not getting any bigger,*

> 'Groan' sounds like 'grown', which indicates something has finished growing

*My homophone's anagram is proved false.*

> The anagram of 'grown' is 'wrong' which means proved false

Comment: Wow, that was fast and correct!

Comment: The third definition ("necessary for life") is not accurate. Single cell creatures can live without it wery well.

Comment: Fixed @LerinSonberg :)