# Kitchen Riddle 3

Tags: riddle

> ```
> My homophone describes some thing multiplied.  
> My anagram's already shown off what's inside. 
>
> My anagram's homophone at one time did abide.  
> The four of us share a homophone on one side.  
>
> Mention to praise invention, you'll find this thing worldwide.  
> As well as bits of me in my anagram if I don't make it inside.
> ```

What am I?

Comment: Whoa! These remind me of my kind of puzzles! Like this one https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/79139/my-anagram-is-noble

Comment: It's no coincidence, I saw that the other day and took inspiration. Thanks for making a great puzzle

Comment: I am flattered :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Bread

My homophone describes some thing multiplied.

> Bred - past tense of breed.

My anagram's already shown off what's inside.

> Bared

My anagram's homophone at one time did abide.

> Beared - possible past tense of *bear*; to endure or carry a burden (definition suggested by AHKieran in the comments).

The four of us share a homophone on one side.

> All four words end in either *red* or *read* which are homophones (with read being in the past tense here).

Mention to praise invention, you'll find this thing worldwide.

> "The greatest thing since sliced bread" 
>  Bread is also prevalent worldwide.

As well as bits of me in my anagram if I don't make it inside.

> You will find bits of bread in your *beard* if it doesn't quite make it in your mouth.

Comment: I think your fourth spoiler block should be rot13("Ornerq" nf va gb orne n oheqra. V guvax guvf qrsvagvba svgf zber jvgu gur pyhr "novqr".)

Comment: @AHKieran yes that is more inline with the definition I had in mind

Comment: Well done hexomino! Solved it really fast.

Comment: The past tense of "orne" in the sense of "novqr" is "ober".