# Me? I cause pain

Tags: word, wordplay, anagram

For context, here is my previous [puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/79139/my-anagram-is-noble) in this format.

> Me, I cause pain.
>
> My first anagram is naturally beautiful.
>
> My second anagram is synonymous with rocks.
>
> My third anagram is fancy food.
>
> My homophone is what two brothers wanted humanity to do.
>
> My homophone’s anagram can direct and achieve motion.
>
> My anagram’s homophone, is how you use the previous clue(plural).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you might be

> Sore

Me, I cause pain.

> Sore is synonymous with "in pain"

My first anagram is naturally beautiful.

> Rose

My second anagram is synonymous with rocks.

> Ores

My third anagram is fancy food.

> Roes

My homophone is what two brothers wanted humanity to do.

> Soar (Wright Brothers)

My homophone’s anagram can direct and achieve motion.

> Oars which is an anagram of "soar" (thanks to bobajob for spotting this in the comments) Coincidentally, it's also a homophone of ores (which makes it "my anagram's homophone").

My anagram’s homophone, is how you use the previous clue(plural).

> Rows (homophone of roes) which is how you use oars

Comment: Nice, but I think your last two have been swapped by mistake...?

Comment: @Stiv, yes you're right, my mistake, thanks!

Comment: Correct @hexomino :)

Comment: While the penultimate clue has the correct answer, it's currently for the wrong reason. It's because it is an anagram of the homophone (the answer just before), not because it is a homophone of the second anagram (which is coincidentally is as well)...

Comment: @bobajob well spotted, my bad reading it.